# How can I skip fields when printing a form if left blank?

Tags: php, html

I have a form built using PHP. While it prints just fine, I want to make it look at each fields and have it skip any div/element/field that's left blank when I decide to print.

Below is an example of the form code in the printable form PHP file. If nothing is filled out/selected, I'd want it to just not appear on the page. What is the best route to achieve this?

Is it as simple as wrapping each form element on the print.php file I have in PHP code or something else?

**CODE**

```
<div class="no-break card">
                    <div class="card-content black-text">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 radio-label">
                                <span class="card-title">PARENT 2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 radio-label">
                                BLANK TEXT 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12">
                                <span class="radio-label">Relationship:</span>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="mother" />
                                    <span>Mother</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="father" />
                                    <span>Father</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="stepmother" />
                                    <span>stepmother</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="stepfather" />
                                    <span>stepfather</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="uncle" />
                                    <span>uncle</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="aunt" />
                                    <span>aunt</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="grandparent" />
                                    <span>grandparent</span>
                                </label>
                                <label class="active" class="radio-button">
                                    <input name="par2relation" type="radio" value="foster parent" />
                                    <span>foster parent</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="par2fname" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2fname">First Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="par2lname" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2lname">Last Name</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="par2phone" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2phone">Phone</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s6">
                                <input id="par2email" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2email">Email</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input id="par2address" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2address">Address</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input id="par2city" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2city">City</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input id="par2state" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2state">State</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-field col s3">
                                <input id="par2zip" type="text"></input>
                                <label class="active" for="par2zip">Zip</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You should be including your PHP code so that we can understand your question better. The more information you give us the better response you will get. That being said, you probably just need to verify that the data you are about to print is not empty using a `if(!empty($datafield))` condition

Comment: @slashroot I didn't include PHP code because it's only querying the DB at the moment since that's all we had to really do up until now. Also, it's a long form. I just took one section of the HTML code to save space

Comment: If you are talking about printing (on paper) the live fillable form, you need a js/css solution. If you are talking about rendering (on screen) a static, submitted/persisted state of the form, then you need a php solution. Please clarify exactly what is the scenario and update the tags as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a CSS media query like

```css
@media print {
.noprint { display: none; }
}
```

And add the `noprint` class to all empty fields via JavaScript.

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(e => {
  if(e.value == '') {
    e.classList.add('noprint');
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

It is pretty typical in PHP to do:

```php
<form>
    <?php if(some condition) { ?>
        <input ...>
    <?php } ?>
</form>
```

It is often a neater way then doing things with print/echo.

If you are planning on doing things like this for large projects or projects that need to be maintainable, you might want to consider using a form builder library(there are loads) which allow you to build form with PHP classes and then generate the HTML.